# Link not working in select box

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails application in which I would like to have active links in each option of my select box that point to the show pages for each respective venue

```
     <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
    <% @venus.each do |ven|%>
      <option><%= link_to ven.name, venue_path(ven.id) %></option>
      <% end %>       
    </select>
  </div>
```

I am sure that there is nothing wrong with the link itself, but when i click on an option on my webpage, nothing happens. I have tested it using dummy links ie

```
<option onClick="window.location = 'http://www.google.com'">A</option>
```

and

```
<option value ='http://www.google.com'>A</option>
```

Everything shows up in my select box but none of the links work. Nothing happens when I click them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onChange` property instead of `onClick`.

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
  <% @venus.each do |ven|%>
    <option><%= link_to ven.name, venue_path(ven.id) %></option>
    <% end %>       
</select>
```